# SQL - Relationship between actors

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a single table with 2 columns: Actors and movies which looks like this:

```
ACTOR  | MOVIE
-------+-------------
Volta  | Pulp Fiction
Bruce  | Pulp Fiction
Rhame  | Pulp Fiction
Walke  | Pulp Fiction
Rhame  | Bad Movie
Bruce  | Bad Movie
Volta  | Decent Movie
Brian  | Decent Movie
Walke  | Awesome Movie
Brian  | Awesome Movie
```

I want to know know which actors, who appeared in Pulp Fiction, never has appeared in another movie with another actor from Pulp Fiction.

From this example, the output should be:

```
Volta
Walke
```

Because they appeared in Pulp Fiction and in Decent Movie and Awesome Movie respectively without any other actors from Pulp Fiction.

I'm using MySQL.

Comment: I don't understand the output you have suggested. Why should Volta be in the output when they were in 'Bad Movie' which also had Bruce in it who was also in 'Pulp Fiction'?

Comment: Sorry. That was a mistake. You are right, I wouldn't want Volta because he appeared with Bruce in Bad Movie. I've changed the data a bit so the output is still correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT m.actor
FROM movies m 
WHERE 
m.movie = 'Pulp Fiction'
AND NOT EXISTS
(
  SELECT 1
  FROM movies m1 
    JOIN movies m2 ON m1.movie = m2.movie 
      AND m1.actor <> m2.actor 
      AND m2.movie <> 'Pulp Fiction' 
      AND m2.actor IN (SELECT actor FROM movies WHERE movie = 'Pulp Fiction')
  WHERE
      m.actor = m1.actor 
)
```

According to [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/557bd/17) done by ChrisProsser it should give the proper result.

Comment: +1 for simple answer. @user2432409 I would be interested to hear whether this solution gets a faster result?

Comment: It works. Not blazing fast. 36 seconds with the 160000 actors and 60000 movies.

Answer (score 0):

There may be an easier way, but this should work:

```
select m.actor 
  from movies m
 where m.movie = 'Pulp Fiction'
   and m.actor not in (
       select m2.actor
         from movies m1,
              movies m2,
              movies m3
        where m1.actor = m2.actor
          and m1.movie = 'Pulp Fiction'
          and m2.movie != m1.movie
          and m3.movie = m2.movie
          and m3.actor in (select m4.actor
                             from movies m4
                            where m4.movie = 'Pulp Fiction')
        group by m2.actor
        having count(*) > 1);
```

I have created a [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/557bd/1/0) to test this and the output is correct.

Comment: My database might not be optimized enough. It can't complete the code, it just keeps running though it. I'll check on some smaller data and approve your answer if it works.

Comment: 160000 actors and 60000 movies.

Comment: @user2432409 Okay, you could probably get a performance gain by creating a distint list of actors in pulp fiction as a temp table to use in place of `movies m` and `movies m4`. Did you want me to add code for this to the answer?

Comment: @kyooryu These tables are joined by actor, so I don't think that should be an issue.

Comment: @ChrisProsser It still can give hundreds of thousands records in return, depending on how often an actor appears in movies.

Answer (score 0):

Try This....

```
SELECT actor, movie 
FROM actor
where movie like 'Pulp Fiction' AND
movie NOT IN(select movie from tablename t where t.actor like actor and movie NOT LIKE 'Pulp Fiction');
```

Comment: All I get is the list of actors who appeared in Pulp Fiction.

Comment: Yes, You will get all list of actor who appeared in 'pulp fiction' and not appeared in other movie.... This was what I got from your question. Is this??? and If this is right I think the above solution is appropriate to salve your issue..

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT actor FROM table AS t1  
WHERE movie = 'Pulp Fiction' AND  
NOT EXISTS( 
  SELECT 1 FROM table AS t2 WHERE t2.actor = t1.actor AND movie <> 'Pulp Fiction' 
)
```

I recommend you to store the movies and actors in different tables (a 'movie' table and a 'actor' table) though and use a 'movie_actor' table to connect the data to each other.

Comment: This searches for actors who have appeared in PF, but not in other movies, doesn't it? This is not what the OP wanted I think.

Comment: Yeah. I want the actors who appeared in PF and then in other movies, but without any of the other actors from PF.